# how to disable highlight for UIButton when the user click on

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

I'm doing a UIButtion that highlight once it clicked and it is un-highlighted when it's clicked again. I can not get to un-highlight when I click on. I have made an event listener below

> - (IBAction)ButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
>     {
>
>   ```
>   [sender setHighlighted:!sender.isHighlighted];
>   ```
>
>   }

Edit:
and the target action is

```
 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[sender setSelected:!sender.isSelected]` try this:) If this is what you want

Comment: [button addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. Put this line: 
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
And in your touch method put [sender setSelected:!sender.isSelected].
It must work

Comment: thank you, it works. but it seems the button  dosen't highlight until i click on it twice then it works normally.

Comment: Sorry, it works perfectly for me. I just tried the same thing:(

Comment: [sender setHighlighted:!sender.isHighlighted]; it works better with me instead of [sender setSelected:!sender.isSelected]. thank you the problem was with event controller.